# Timeout after URL requests statement

Tags: python, python-requests, timeoutexception

I currently have some code which is designed to try to do a URL request and if any exceptions are thrown to acknowledge them and proceed.

```
    try:
        x = requests.get(URL)

    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print('timeout error, proceed to next URL')
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print('too many redirects, proceed to next URL')
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print('request exception, proceed to next URL')
```

However, with the try statement, sometimes a URL will  be requested and the request will go on for hours and hours and never throw a Timeout exception.Essentially it goes into try and executes requests.get(URL) and it just gets stuck. Not sure why this is happening.

How can I make it catch the timeout error so it doesn't get stuck and just moves on after a specified amount of time (like 10s or something)?

Edit: The URLs are valid URLs that link to actual websites, and the loop is set up correctly, that is not the problem.

Comment: try specifying custom timeout in request, like: requests.get(url, timeout=5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Request object takes in various parameters, one of them being `timeout`. If you do not pass any value, by defualt value is None, which means, request will only terminate when the connection is closed. Hence try specifying a custom 'timeout' in your request. I think 10 Seconds should be good to go.